# Pinging an IP and port with C#

Tags: c#, ping

I am able to ping an IP using a code like below:

```
Ping pinger = new Ping();
PingReply reply = pinger.Send(IP_Address, timeout);
```

How can I target a specific port also (say port 80) in the ping?

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/37897

Comment: You can't. You can try checking the port with Tcp connection though.